# Why is this derivative of an integral calculated in this way?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Could anyone please give me an insight as to why the following derivative is correct?

The function to derivate is
$$f(x) = -ax +b\int_{-\infty}^xF(\xi)d\xi$$

The result is
$$f'(x) = -a + bF(x)$$

Particularly, I do not understand how the integral is resolved to $bF(x)$. What rule am I missing?

Comment: How does $F$ behave?  Does it have an asymptote toward $-\infty$?

Comment: Oh, well being a CDF is very strong, and it matters.

Comment: I think there's a little more to it than that, as the integral is improper.

Comment: @Randall No, FTC is all there is to it. Of course we need to add an assumption that the integral exists, but given that, $\int_{-\infty}^x==\int_{-\infty}^0+\int_0^x$. The first term on the RHS is constant and FTC applies to the second term.

Comment: I understand that, but that is an extra step that is not in the ordinary statement of the FTC.  Either way, it should be considered, especially for a beginning student.

Comment: You should definitely have some assumption that the integral exists, but once it does, there should be no problem. Note that $F$ being a CDF is not sufficient to imply that the integral considered is finite. Consider for instance the measure on $(-\infty,0]$ which assigns mass $\frac{1}{2^n}$ to the point $-2^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Well first, the differentiation is *not* correct unless you make some more assumptions about $F$; you really need to tell us what you know about $F$ here.

For example, let $a=0$, $b=1$ and $$F(\xi)=\begin{cases}
0,&(\xi<0),
\\1,&(\xi\ge0).\end{cases}$$Then $f'(0)$ does not exist. (Note that this $F$ *is* a CDF...)

But the result in question is just a special case of FTC if you assume (of course) that $\int_{-\infty}^0F$ exists and that $F$ is *continuous*. Contrary to one of the comments, the fact that it's an improper integral is no problem here:

> > **FTC.** Suppose $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $I(x)=\int_a^x F(\xi)$ for $x\in [a,b]$.  Then $I'=F$ on $(a,b)$.

Now assuming that $\int_{-\infty}^0F$ exists and that $F$ is continuous, write $$I(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x F=\int_{-\infty}^0+\int_0^x=I_1(x)+I_2(x).$$Now $I_1$ is constant, and FTC shows that $I_2'(x)=F(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Assume the antiderivative of $F$ to be $G$.

Now what is the derivative of

$$-ax+b(G(x)-G(-\infty))\ ?$$

Comment: @PeterForeman: of course. Anyway this is a little symbolic, as $G(-\infty)$ is not deemed to be a legal expression.

Answer (score 0):

The [fundamental theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) says essentially that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(z)dz = f(x)$, so the function that has as its variable the upper limit of some integral over a function is differentiable with value $f(x)$. (normally stated for finite intervals, but valid too for integrable functions on infinite ones, as here)

Comment: Valid for integrable functions? This is big news...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I was referring to arguments like in you comment, splitting off the indefinite part (provided it's finite).

Comment: Of course there's no problem with what you meant; I was referring to what you wrote. Just bugged that everyone seems to be ignoring the fact that FTC has _hypotheses_...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich you mean hypotheses such as the lower limit being constant? ;)

Comment: No, I mean hypotheses like I specified in my answer; in particular it's enough to assume that $F$ is continuous and $\int_{-\infty}^0F$ exists.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I fully agree with the sentiments. The OP didn't specify any conditions either. The idea was just to point him in the direction of looking up FCT, essentially; it's then up to the OP to check the relevant version's conditions, I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
f(x) = -ax +b\int_{-\infty}^0F(\xi)d\xi +b\int_{0}^xF(\xi)d\xi
= -ax +f(0) +b\int_{0}^xF(\xi)d\xi
$$
The claim now follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus if $F$ is continuous.

Comment: From a comment by  David C. Ullrich.